# Vue date values, getting current day minus 1 day in ISO format

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an issue with my Vue data return using date values for picker so that I can set endDate as the current date and startDate as the current day - 1. The below example gives me today's date properly as `endDate` but trying this method for startDate isn't giving me anything.

What's the appropriate way to set the default startDate as the current date - 1 day in Vue?

```
data(){
  return{
    startDate: new Date()-1.toISOString().substring(0,10),
    endDate: new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10),
  }
}
```

Comment: `1.toISOString()` - 1 doesn't have a toISOString method

Comment: try `new Date(Date.now()-86400000).toISOString().substring(0,10)` ... - 86400000 becuase that's how many milliseconds are in a day

Comment: Maybe it is worth looking at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Bravo thank you that actually did work! I didn't think about that. Feel free to make an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds in a day, that's how much you have to subtract to go back a day

However, the way you are doing it is not right in another way

```
new Date()-1.toISOString().substring(0,10)
```

basically does

```
new Date() - (1.toISOString().substring(0,10))
```

What will work is

```
new Date(Date.now()-86400000).toISOString().substring(0,10)
```

Since Date.now() returns the current time in milliseconds